# log4net - Optional MessageBox

Tags: c#, log4net

We are using log4net for the logging in our programs. In some of these programs we log the errors in a file and show a message box at the same time. I solved this by creating an own "MessageBoxAppender". This is working fine.

The problem is we have a program which can be split into two big parts. The first part is the configuration and the second part is an automatic task which processes some data and executes different modules. The problem is we only want to have the MessageBoxAppender for the configuration part. For the automatic part there must not be any message boxes, because in this case the programm will be stopped, which is not the behavior we want to have. Is there any possibility to deactivate an appender temporarily? (Or any other better solution?)

Comment: Appenders are only active when you make them active.  How are you configuring log4net?  Programatically or through a config file?

Comment: I'm using a config file. I tried to remove the MessageBoxAppender in the classes where I don't need it. But the problem is there are some functionalities which are used for the configuration part and for the automatic process. So it's not possible and I think it would be an awful solution in general.

Comment: Do your config process and automatic process share config files? Can you split them out into different config files?  Then you can configure log4net differently in them.

Comment: That's the problem, both are using the same config. And it is not possible to change that easily.

Comment: Set up two loggers, one which uses the MessageBoxAppender, and one that doesn't. then just use the correct logger in each place.

Comment: The problem is there a classes which I need in both parts, for example the loading of the configuration from the database. Therefore it's not possible to use two loggers.